# Wordpress add jquery limited to plugin only

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am creating a plugin in wordpress

I have added few jQuery lines to override basic wordpress functionality and include this file by using wp_register_script and wp_enqueue_script.

But i want that this file to be include only if admin is on my plugin pages so these lines executes only for my plugin page.

I need to know is there any way so i can know whether admin is on my plugin pages or not.

Please help, comment if you need more info regarding question.

Update :

I know i can do so by adding

```
if($_GET['page']=='my_plugin_page') {
    //my code
}
```

But for this i have to write if statement for all my pages, i want to use some nice method than this..

Answer (score 1):

Check if the current_user can manage_options.  This will indicate that they are admin.

PHP:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    /* A user with admin privileges */
} else {
    /* A user without admin privileges */
}
```

Comment: Rob i do not want to check whether user is admin or not, instead i want to execute jquery only if admin is on my plugin pages..

Comment: Well then you'd include the javascript files if they're an admin.

Comment: The plugins are not executed on the other backend pages – so this solutions comes pretty close to your requirements.

Comment: Ben, Feeela thanks for your comments, let me give you another example.. using jquery i have forced wordpress menu to show my plugin links in a unique way.. but when i visit some other page of wordpress such as dashboard the jquery still executes which i do not want to.

Comment: You need to only add the jQuery lines in the PHP files of your plugin dashboard then.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to check that admin is logged in

```
<?
get_currentuserinfo() ;
global $user_level;
if ($user_level > 9) {
    //user is admin and add your js file
}
```

//OR

```
  if ( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
    /* Your code */
  }
```

//OR

```
if(is_admin() === true) {
 /*your code*/
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mypage = add_management_page( 'myplugin', 'myplugin', 9, __FILE__, 'myplugin_admin_page' );
add_action( "admin_print_scripts-$mypage", 'myplugin_admin_head' );

function myplugin_admin_head() {
    // what your plugin needs in its <head>
}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: It adds sub menu page to the tools main menu